# Visual Studio online: How to set permissions to certain parts of my Solution

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I created a Solution with several Sup Projects

Here is a Screen shot:

[image]

We are using Visual Studio Online for our Source control (GIT)

[image]

The complete solution is one repository. Now I would like a user to have access only to the projects "N" & "R" and work on those. He should not be able to access any code from the other two.

How would I set this up?

Can I limit the access somehow on Visual Studio Online (VSO)?
Or do I have to split the Solution somehow. Do I need a separte Team Projects on VSO for each project? Do I need separte Repos?

Thanks for you help in advance
Karl

Comment: You could accomplish this with submodules

Comment: So what you suggest is: